# Update a single value in a mongodb 2d array

Tags: mongodb

Say i have the following structure in a mongodb document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("592eae9a92e32cc41c1c9af7"),
    source: [
        [ a, b, c, d],
        [ a, b, c, d],
        [ a, b, 1, d]
    ]

}
```

And i know that the row: 2 and the column to update is 2 (zero indexed).

How would i change the value 1 to c?

Answer (score 1):

Ok panic over. Apparently this works!

```
db.collection.update(
    {_id : ObjectId('592eae9a92e32cc41c1c9af7')},
    {
        $set : {
            'source.2.2': 'c'         
        }     
    }
);
```